# How to access iPhone SMS db?

Tags: iphone, database, sms

I am beginner in iPhone technology so i don't have much idea how to access iPhone SMS db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access iPhone database to access mobile library path and appending `SMS.db` file with that  path you will get the access to iPhone SMS.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in JailBreak Phone,you can access the SMS by using this path :-

> /private/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make a backup of the iPhone in iTunes, then access the backup file location, explained here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204215

Once you are in the backup folder, you can search for the sms.db file by its hashed filename - 3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28 for sms.db

When you find the file, copy and paste the file somewhere else - you can rename the new copy sms.db if you want. It's a SQLite db so open in the editor of your choice. In theory you can edit the db, replace the original file in the backup and then restore it to your iPhone.

A list of other interesting files in the iTunes backup can be found here:
https://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/blog/iphone-backup-location-all-files-extension/

Answer (score 0):

You can't access SMS db programmatically. There is no public `API` Provided by `Apple`.

Comment: Given that the file is a basic a sqlite3 db file you can programmatically access it and 2 methods were mentioned above. I feel like this post should be removed. It may not be accessible without a backup or a jailbreak, but it is clearly accessible.