# What is the Path for Call_History.db in iOS 6. Is it same as that of iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, call

I am new at iPhone development. I want to access iOS6 call_history. My code work for iOS5 but not work for iOS6. please help me to solve this problem. Many Thanks.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: thanks for reply me. I used this link for my coding. http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Comment: OK, it's the same tutorial as I posted on the answer. It  will not work on iOS 6 because security is more severe and you do not have access to that file, it also shouldn't work on iOS5... strange.

Comment: We used path for call_history is /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db and it's working for us in iOS5 but not in iOS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the call log using the SDK and approved APIs. There are some workarounds, as you probably already know. The only option I know about is accessing `call_history.db`.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/). Unfortunately for you, security has been made more severe, and you only can access that file in iOS < 5.0 (and probably all jailbreacked versions).

Comment: Thanks. One more difficult is that. If i want to access SMS.db than what can i do ?

Comment: Here is an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756229/how-to-access-iphone-sms-db). But, probably, the access on higher iOS versions will be blocked as well.