# Acessing system information from frameworks in iOS Developer Library

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

As the title says, I am trying to create an app(personal development) and try to see what kind of **system information** or **user data** can be retrieved from phone. For now I am using the stimulator provided. So far what I am able to do is to retrieve information using the **Address Book** and **UIKit** Framework such as contact details and System Name/Version etc.

Is there any system information/user data that I missed out because I have yet to know of any more frameworks that allows retrieving of any information from the phone/Stimulator. I am not able to test **EventKit** Framework(the only other framework that  I know) due to the fact that I am deploying the app in the stimulator which does not have the required apps. (Will be trying on jailbroken iphone in the later stages).

Also, I have yet to find any information of accessing the `.sqlitedb /.db/.plist` files programmatically instead of using any software tools as I would like to access the files such as messages, phone history through my app that I created. If this is possible, I would also like to know if accessing these `.sqlitedb /.db files/.plist` is only applicable if I deploy my app in the jailbroken phone `/Applications` folder which does not have sandbox or is it also applicable in the stimulator itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822031/call-history-sms-history-email-history-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be definitely helpful to you to get access the call/sms/email details by reading the .sqlite database. Here is a [tutorial](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/).

Comment: Hi I have came across this before but reading the comments given many said that this is not workable for iOS5 and above? Maybe you can clarify this for me? Is it not workable for unjailbroken phone that has firmware 5 and above but still workable for any firmware of jailbroken phone?

Comment: You are right. From ios 5, apple didn't gave access to the database.

Comment: Just to be sure, apple does not allow access to any.db files which are of iOS5 and above, whether jailbroken or not , or only unjailbroken devices that is iOS5 and above?

Comment: Yes, apple is not allowing for iOS5 and above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654495/what-is-the-path-for-call-history-db-in-ios-6-is-it-same-as-that-of-ios5 As u can see, this person is able to do access .db files in iOS5(not sure about the credibility) and the answer provided mentioned that you can access the .db files if your phone is jailbroken(if i read it correctly). So I am very confused.

Comment: You can give a try with iOS5, if worked then charm for you and also share your experience here, will be helpful for us.

Comment: BTW, he mentioned "iOS < 5.0" means less than 5 not working on 5.

Comment: i was deciphering what he mentioned "(and probably all jailbreacked versions)".

Answer (score 1):

i know providing links are discouraged here however these [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html)   and [wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/Frameworks)

links will be helpful to you.

thanks

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your links. Read through it and I found out about IOKit for hardware information and CoreTelephony for carrier information. Not sure if I missed out any others. Would be great if you could fill me up any that i did not mention. :)